# Android instrumentation tests clear settings in my application

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

The problem is:

1. I run my application. Settings are present and everything is fine.
2. I run instrumentation tests (gradle task **connectedCheck**). Tests not operate with settings (not read, not remove, even don't touch). Test are annotated with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` and aren't using activities at all.
3. I run my app again and I have to specify settings like I reinstalled my app.

I've tried to specify `testApplicationId` in gradle buildscript:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    testApplicationId "something.package"
```

But it has no effect.

Why it is happening, and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Gradle User-guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-tests):

> As mentioned previously, checks requiring a connected device are
>   launched with the anchor task called `connectedCheck`. This depends on
>   the task `connectedDebugAndroidTest` and therefore will run it. This
>   task does the following:
>
> - Ensure the app and the test app are built
>     (depending on `assembleDebug` and `assembleDebugAndroidTest`).
> - Install both apps.
> - Run the tests.
> - **Uninstall both apps.**

You can use the regular run-configuration to launch tests instead of `connectedCheck`:

[image: Run Android Tests]

Comment: Thanks, this works and solves the problem. Unfortunately is has a huge shortcoming - by executing gradle task I get back readable report in html, by executing such run configuration I don't (

Comment: @Alexey, hi. Sorry for late comment, but did you find better solution to execute tests with saving the application state?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov, I would post it there, but unfortunately I haven't found the better solution :(